# Why doesn't this assembly program work correct?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to make a simple x86 assembly code, which gets an input from the user, and then matches that against a hardcoded password in the memory, and prints a message to the user accordingly (correct/incorrect).

Here is my code:

```
%macro write_string 2 
    mov   eax, 4
    mov   ebx, 1
    mov   ecx, %1
    mov   edx, %2
    int   80h
%endmacro

%macro read_string 2
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, %1
    mov edx, %2
    int 80h
%endmacro

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    write_string msg, lenMsg

    read_string string, 32

    mov [readBytes], eax

    mov ecx, 0
    l1:
        mov eax, string
        add eax, ecx

        mov byte al, [eax]

        mov eax, pwd
        add eax, ecx

        mov byte bl, [eax]

        cmp bl, al
        jne incorrect
        inc ecx
        cmp ecx, [readBytes]
        jne l1

    correct:
        write_string txt1, txt1Len
        jmp exit

    incorrect:
        write_string txt2, txt2Len

    exit:
        write_string lineBreak, 1
        mov eax,1
        int 0x80



section .bss
    readBytes: resb   1

section .data

msg db 'Password: '
lenMsg equ $ - msg

string times 100 db 0

pwd  db 'secretPass1'

txt1 db 'Correct', 0xa
txt1Len equ $ - txt1
txt2 db 'Incorrect', 0xa
txt2Len equ $ - txt2

lineBreak db 0xa
```

The program compiles, but when I run it and type an input, it always prints the "incorrect" message, even though I used the right password.

Can you tell me what I did wrong?

And I have another question, what's the difference between:

```
section .bss
    string: resb   100
```

and:

```
section .data
    string times 100 db 0
```

For allocating uninitialized data?

Thanks

Comment: _"Can you tell me what I did wrong?"_ You haven't even told us what's going wrong when you run it.

Comment: What is the value of `readBytes` after the string has been read?

Comment: @Michael I believe it's the length of the string the user put in.

Comment: The point is, if all your assumptions were correct, you wouldn't be having any issues. But since you do have an issue you should verify everything, and the contents of `readBytes` and `string` would be a good place to start.

Comment: `mov byte al, [eax]` sets register `al` to the input byte. However, `mov eax, pwd` then overwrites `al` because `al` is the low 8 bits of `eax`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> mov byte al, [eax]
> mov eax, pwd
> ```

As [ecm told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63555332/why-doesnt-this-assembly-program-work-correct#comment112386997_63555332), loading the address to *pwd* overwrites the character already loaded in the `AL` register.
You could solve this by using a different register for traversing *pwd* OR you could correct it and simplify the code by using a different addressing mode:

```
  mov [readBytes], eax
  xor ecx, ecx
Verify:
  mov dl, [string + ecx]
  mov bl, [pwd + ecx]
  cmp dl, bl
  jne incorrect
  inc ecx
  cmp ecx, eax            ; No need to compare with a memory based variable
  jb  Verify
```

There are additional problems:

- In the .bss you reserved **1 byte** for the *readBytes* variable that is in fact a dword and so requires **4 bytes** of storage. Because you're only using that one variable in the .bss, you won't notice the error now, but wait until you (have to) write a program with more variables!
- Your password verification loop runs over all of the inputted characters disregarding the fact that if the input was **longer or shorter (including empty)** than the stored password, it becomes futile to compare the characters.

  ```
      mov [readBytes], eax
      cmp eax, 11          ; Length of the hardcode password 'secretPass1'
      jne incorrect
      xor ecx, ecx
    Verify:
  ```

---

The difference between `resb 100` (.bss) and `times 100 db 0` (.data).

`times 100 db 0` is performed by the assembler. It physically puts this many zero bytes in your executable. You're guaranteed that the memory will contain 100 zero bytes.
`resb 100` is 'performed' by the OS when the program starts. Many times this memory will also contain zero bytes but the idea is that you should not count on this to be true.